# How to ignore space, capital letters and punctuation in string using HashMap?

Tags: java, string, collections, hashmap

Hello I´m trying to write program which is counting all characters in given string using HashMap and then it prints result on console like:

{a=2, s=2, k=1, m=1, o=1}

So far I have something like this:

```
public void result(String sentence) {
    int value;
    HashMap<Character, Integer> mp = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        if (mp.containsKey(sentence.charAt(i))) {
            value = mp.get(sentence.charAt(i));
            value++;
            mp.put(sentence.charAt(i), value);

        } else {
            mp.put(sentence.charAt(i), 1);
        }
    }

    System.out.print(mp);
}
```

I want to ask how can I ignore spaces, capital letter and punctuation in that given string. 
So it will not show in result?

I hope someone will help me thank you!

Comment: You can't do this inside the map.  You will have to do this to each character yourself before interacting with the map.

Comment: `if (Character.isLowerCase(sentence.charAt(i))) { /* add it to the map */ }`

Comment: @shmosel that only works if he *actually* wants to ignore uppercase characters, as opposed to being case-insensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend filtering out the characters you don't want before passing it into the `HashMap`.

For example,

```
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
```

Would remove anything other than a lowercase letter, and

```
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("[^a-z0-9]", "");
```

Would leave you with lower-case letters and numbers.

If you want to convert uppercase letters to lowercase instead of ignoring them, then first use

```
sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved me! :) I did not know that Java have this function...

Answer (score 0):

You could check the ascii value of the current character and if it's in the given range 'a' (97) and 'z' (122) you would add it to the map, otherwise you ignore it.

```
    if (mp.containsKey(sentence.charAt(i))) {
        ...
    } else if(sentence.charAt(i) >= 'a' || sentence.charAt(i) <= 'z') {
        mp.put(sentence.charAt(i), 1);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ignoring - " + sentence.charAt(i));
    }
```

This would prevent any extra traversing of the sentence and clean up before having to create your map. O(1)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd approach the task:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String source = "Here comes another challenger!";
    Map<Character, Integer> characterCounts = countCharacters(source);
    System.out.println("Source string \"" + source + "\" gives map:\n"
            + characterCounts);
}

public static Map<Character, Integer> countCharacters(String source) {
    Map<Character, Integer> characterCounts = new HashMap<>(64);
    source.chars().map(LetterCounter::lowercaseCharacter).filter(
            LetterCounter::isCharactedCounted).forEach(c
                    -> characterCounts.merge((char) c, 1, (o, n) -> o + 1));
    return characterCounts;
}

public static int lowercaseCharacter(int characterValue) {
    char character = (char) characterValue;
    return (int) Character.toLowerCase(character);
}

public static boolean isCharactedCounted(int character) {
    if (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Running the example `main` method gives the output:

```
Source string "Here comes another challenger!" gives map:
{a=2, c=2, e=6, g=1, h=3, l=2, m=1, n=2, o=2, r=3, s=1, t=1}
```

The `countCharacters` method is creating an `IntStream` of the characters found within the given String, but this is just an elegant/compact/lazy way of doing exactly the same thing you're doing with a for loop. The `Stream.map` method calls `lowercaseCharacter(int)` to turn the `int` character value into a lowercase character `int` value. Then the `filter` method is discarding all the characters which cause the method `isCharactedCounted` to return `false` because we don't want those. Then `forEach` is used to process every character from the string which does interest us (the code in `forEach` is called each time the character is found in the string). The `Map.merge` method is just an elegant/compact/lazy way of doing exactly what you're already doing with your get,++,put code. Then the finished map is returned.

You can customise the `isCharacterCounted` method to suit your needs. Note that this method takes an `int` primitive and not a `char` (because the `String.chars()` method returns a stream of `int` and not a stream of `char`). However, in Java a `char` is really just an `int` anyway, so the two are basically interchangeable, so long as you remember to use the correct type cast when needed. (Note that in the call to `Map.merge` we have to cast the `int c` into `(char) c` because the map is expecting a `Character` and an `int` cannot be auto-boxed into a `Character`. And we need to create the utility method `lowercaseCharacter` to convert an `int` character value into a lowercase `int` character value.)